elliptic curves on fields with characteristic 2
Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $2$. Further, let $\varepsilon$ be an elliptic curve. I should now proof, that $\#\epsilon[2] \leq 2$.
I started with the following general expression of an elliptic curve
$Y^2 + aXY + bY - (X^3 + cX^2 + dX + e) = 0$
And I know that $P + P = 0$ for $P \in \varepsilon$ if and only if $P = -P = (x_0, -y_0 + ax_0 + b)$. This implied, that for $(x,y) \in \varepsilon$, I get $ax + b = 0$ and $y^2 = (X^3 + cX^2 + dX + e)$. Thus if $a$ has an inverse, there is at most one element $P \neq 0$ with this property. On the other side, if $a = 0$, I know that every point on my elliptic curve must have the property:
$Y^2 - (X^3 + cX^2 + dX + e) = 0$
Now I can't come up with an idea, why this elliptic curve has at most 2 elements. Does anyone have a hint for me? I am grateful for any help!

Do you know that the Frobenius map is purely inseparable? The result follows from this, plus the fact that $[2] = \widehat{\operatorname{Frob}_2} \circ \operatorname{Frob}_2$.

@ViktorVaughn Thank you for your Input. We did not introduce the term purely inseparable in the lecture. But I can see why the Frobenius map is purely inseparable. We also didn't talk about the property $[2] = \widehat{\operatorname{Frob}_2} \circ \operatorname{Frob}_2$.

Is such a curve non-singular in characteristic two?

@Ruebli Okay, the details of this approach are spelled out in Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Corollary III.6.4.

@ViktorVaughn Thank you. I'm gonna look into it!

@dan_fulea Thank you for your Input. I'm not sure if it is. I started this approach before asking the question here, but I didn't get to a conclusion yet.
